# watir-webdriver Modal Dialog error

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

```
[remote server] file:///C:/Users/abdia/AppData/Local/Temp/webdriver-profile20120
326-6092-6x0lwb/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.
js:10583:in `unknown': Modal dialog present (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::Unhandl
edAlertError)
```

When clicking on this link

```
<%= link_to "Delete", user, :class => user.email,:method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

I'm getting the error above, is there anyway to tell watir-webdriver to click OK on the JS dialog box that opens?

EDIT:

html output

```
<a href="/users/1" class="ahmet.abdi@dai.co.uk" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

I find this by

```
b.a(:class => 'example@dai.co.uk').click
```

Comment: It fails after you click link? If yes, what do you do after clicking?

Comment: Sorry, but is that updated WATIR locator literal ('example@dai.co.uk'?).  Unless that's pseudo-code, that's not going to locate what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah sorry thats just an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"

browser.confirm(true) do
  browser.link(text: 'Delete').click
end
```

You can also try to handle directly using WebDriver

```
browser.link(text: 'Delete').click
# when modal dialog is shown
browser.driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss
```

Comment: Updated answer with WebDriver-based solution

Comment: Still crashes with Modal dialog present

Comment: I just tested it locally and it works. You have to show use your Watir code and point when confirm dialog occurs.